# Replace algorithm with array_intersect - order of arguments question

Tags: php, array-intersect

I have an algorithm that does some product categories calculations in WordPress... The parts of interest of the algorithm are below:

```
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        if ( check_children( $product_category->term_id, $product_ids ) ) {
            // Here we perform some calculations when $product_category->term_id's children categories (their IDs actually) aren't included in the array (of IDs) $product_ids
        }
    }
```

The `check_children` function is this:

```
function check_children( $parent, $term_ids = array() ) {
    $is_latest_child = true;
    $children        = get_term_children( $parent, 'product_cat' ); // For those not familiar with WP, this function returns an array of category IDs that are children of the "$parent" category at question
    if ( count( $children ) > 0 ) { // First of all, this count is obsolete, isn't it? I mean, foreach below already takes care of the case when $children is empty, isn't this so?
        foreach ( $children as $child ) {
            if ( in_array( $child, $term_ids ) ) { // So all that's needed is at least one child category of the $parent at question to be included in the array of "prohibited" categories in $term_ids
                $is_latest_child = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $is_latest_child;
}
```

So what I want is either optimize, or better yet completely wipe the use of `check_children` with the use of `array_intersect`... But I'm a little confused about the correct order of arguments. Let me be more specific:

I'm planning to replace this:

```
if ( check_children( $product_category->term_id, $product_ids ) ) {
```

with this (I'm leaning towards this more):

```
if ( count( array_intersect( get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_cat' ), $product_ids ) ) === 0 ) {
```

or is it this the correct one:

```
if ( count( array_intersect( $product_ids, get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) ) === 0 ) {
```

Or doesn't it actually really matter? Remember I want to replace my already existing algorithm with this sorter "workaround".

(I have one or two questions in a comment in the second code block. Could you please answer those too?)

TIA.

Comment: "First of all, this count is obsolete, isn't it? I mean, foreach below already takes care of the case when $children is empty, isn't this so?" yes

Comment: Either order of parameters is fine. But I would keep `check_children` and move the `array_intersect` in there, it is much easier to read `check_children( $product_category->term_id, $product_ids )` than `count( array_intersect( $product_ids, get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) ) === 0`

Comment: @Nick could you foresee any case where this `count` might really server a purpose? The group of coders who wrote this piece of code consists of very well trained people, and I wonder why they may have used the `count` there....

Comment: It's hard to say whether there's a good reason for generating the count or whether there might have been in a previous version. Certainly there's no reason in the code you have posted.

Comment: @Nick but for some reason you picked the second scenario (not the one I was leaning towards to). Was that for readability reasons of the piece of code?

Comment: No, that was just the first code my mouse landed on! :)

Comment: Ah, OK. So, in reality (at least when we're talking about just two arrays), there is no difference between the two variations of argument order. But technically (or if I had to check against more arrays), the first (the one I'm leaning towards to) scenario is the correct, isn't it?

Comment: Assuming that `get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_cat' )` had the least number of entries in it, then having it first in the list should be more efficient.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use `count() === 0`, `!array_intersect()` will work the same.  We don't need this question to remain open, right?  Oh, and yeah, the `foreach()` will ignore empty arrays naturally/silently.